# AJAX won't execute all of the php code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ffmpeg

I want a progressbar to be shown while a video-file is being uploaded. I'm using JS and AJAX to track progress of the file-upload php, and send the file. The php file contains a ffmpeg command that grabs some frames from the video. Essentially the php file creates a random folder, and puts both the video and the frames in it. when the php is called by `if(isset($_FILES['file']))` it works just fine. But when i try to use AJAX it only uploads the video, but ignores the ffmpeg command and mysql_query.

**Javascript:**

```
function uploadFile(){
        var file = _("file1").files[0];
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file1", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
```

**Upload.php**

```
        $name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
        $type = explode(".",$name);
        $type = end($type);
        $tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $exp = explode(".",$name);
        $filename = rand().$exp[0];
        $path = "videos/" . $filename . "/" . $name;
        $ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
        $size = "320x180";

        if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4'){

          $message = "Only mp4 format is supported!";
          $uploadOk = 0; 

        }else{

          mkdir("videos/".$filename);

          // ffmpeg function 
          for($num = 1; $num <= 15; $num++){
          $interval = $num * 3;
          shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $tmp -an -ss $interval -s $size /videos/$filename/thumb$num.png");}

          move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name, url) VALUES('$name', '$path')");
```

Why dosen't AJAX execute the complete php?

Comment: oops, looks like some code went missing while chipping down on the code. -updated.

Comment: I would recommend adding `-frames 1` - it seems to make creating thumbs far quicker - it may well be a time issue you are having

Comment: you're executing ffmpeg 15 times, making a frame each time, right, for 3, 6, 9 ... 45 seconds into the mp4 ... when I tested how long your command would take, I noticed it took longer and longer the larger -ss was - with -frames 1 this lag disappeared (for me)

Comment: I was wondering what the ffmpeg command line would be, you'll have to excuse me, i'm very new to ffmpeg.

Comment: not sure if this will fix your issue, but, fyi add the -frames 1 like so `$ffmpeg -i $tmp -an -ss $interval -frames 1 -s $size /videos/$filename/thumb$num.png`

Comment: hmm yeah, don't think will solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible the filename sometimes contains spaces, such that the ffmpeg call looks like `$ffmpeg -i $tmp -an -ss $interval -s $size /videos/{rand()}this file/thumb$num.png`? either way it's probably worth coding for that eventuality. EDIT: Actually looking again, if this is to be public, there are a few places you may want to properly sanitize user input before concatenating it into a shell command, lest you leave yourself open to injection.

Comment: try printing the value of `$ffmpeg` make sure points to full path of ffmpeg binary